# How do I make a query using PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to make this query using PDO and it is returning and error.I have already verified the connection to the database.

```
function temperaturaMedia($data_inicio,$data_final,$ema)
{

  $db = 'sensorzapp_db';

  $query = "SELECT
        DATE(DTM) AS 'Dia',
        ROUND(AVG(TMP),1) AS 'Temp. Med.'
        FROM dados_meteo
        WHERE POM = '$ema'
        AND DATE(DTM) BETWEEN '$data_inicio' AND '$data_final'
        GROUP BY DATE(DTM)";

  $stmt = $db->query($query);
  return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to execute a query on a string, you need to connect to the database, like this:

```
function temperaturaMedia($data_inicio,$data_final,$ema)
{

  try {
  $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=sensorzapp_db","user","password");
  } catch($ex) { die("Connection failed"); } // To not disclosure username & password when connection fails (look at the red box on http://www.php.net/manual/de/pdo.connections.php)
  $query = "SELECT
        DATE(DTM) AS 'Dia',
        ROUND(AVG(TMP),1) AS 'Temp. Med.'
        FROM dados_meteo
        WHERE POM = '$ema'
        AND DATE(DTM) BETWEEN '$data_inicio' AND '$data_final'
        GROUP BY DATE(DTM)";

  $stmt = $db->query($query);
  return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```